# Cannot find screen.css compass/sass in django project that is compiling correctly

Tags: css, django, compass-sass, static-linking

I have a django project that I did `compass init` to make new compass folders inside. My compass/sass is compiling when I make changes inside it, but my template is not taking any of these changes or working properly- in the debugger I get 404 error loading 'screen.css', but it finds bootstrap properly.

In base.htm, which all templates extend:

```
{% block main_header %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Sitename</title>
        <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
        {% block custom_stylesheets %}{% endblock %}
        <link href="/stylesheets/screen.css" media="screen, projection" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
{% endblock %}
```

In settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'bootstrapform',
    'djcompass',
)

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles'),
)

SETTINGS_PATH = os.path.dirname(__file__)
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.join(SETTINGS_PATH, os.pardir)
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.abspath(PROJECT_PATH)

    os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__)) + '/templates/',
)

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

in screen.scss:

```
@import "compass/reset";
@import "partials/weekly_schedule";
```

in _weekly_schedule.scss:

```
@import 'compass/css3/box-shadow';
@import 'compass/css3/box-sizing';

.tabbed-content-box{
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 16px 5px 5px 5px;
}
...etc...
```

In the template in question, weekly_schedule.htm:

```
{% extends 'base.htm' %}
{% load extras form_fields bootstrap %}

{% block body_block %}
    <form id="schedule_form" method="post" action="{% url 'owners:weekly_schedule' biz.slug %}"
            enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}

        {% for i in 7|get_range %}
            {% day_field day_dict i schedule_form %}
        {% endfor %}

<div style="clear;"></div>
<br/>

   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Set schedule" />

    <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

{% endblock %}
```

In the past, my issue was in the importing of 'compass/css3' which made no sense, since I started a compass project. This is no longer griping at the moment. My screen.css seems to be compiling well, saying things like

```
/* line 93, ../sass/partials/_weekly_schedule.scss */
.faketestthingy {
  background-color: red;
}
```

after I make a fake entry. Most importantly, in config.rb, which is at the root level in the project (the place compass init put it) I have:

```
#http_path = "/home/myname/django_practice/scheduler_app"
http_path = "/"
css_dir = "stylesheets"
sass_dir = "sass"
```

of which I have tried both http_paths, to no avail. I can't remember why I changed my PROJECT_PATH in the past (it was a static files thing) but I tried that without the absolute path as well. I tried changing all the media settings that had "static/staticfiles" to "stylesheets", and still 404 on screen.css. Any pointers greatly appreciated. Thank you
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep your layout this way, you need to add `stylesheets` to your `STATICFILES_DIRS`:

**1) Updating `STATICFILES_DIRS`**

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'stylesheets'),
)
```

---

**2) Updating `base.html`**

– load `staticfiles`
– embed the stylesheet using the `{% static %}` tag

```
{% load staticfiles %}
{% block main_header %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Sitename</title>
        <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
        {% block custom_stylesheets %}{% endblock %}
        <link href="{% static "screen.css" %}" media="screen, projection" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
{% endblock %}
```

---

*Update:* **Why it wasn't working before**

Especially in the beginning it takes a bit of time to get a feeling for the separation of what Django calls static and media files and the Python/Django code that drives the app.

The important bit is that from your directory layout, no directory is accessible from your webserver. This is why if we want to use custom directory layouts we need to tell Django about the directories where we put static assets (css, javascript, images, fonts, ..). We do that by adding the `STATICFILES_DIRS` setting:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'stylesheets'),
)
```

Now Django knows to look for static files in both of these directories. That's a first step.

The next important thing is the `STATIC_URL` setting:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

This tells Django the base URL to expose the static files. Let's say we have these files

```
/staticfiles/
    logo.jpg
    bg_tile.png
    js/
      app.js  
/stylesheets/
    styles.css
    styles_mobile.css
```

With the above settings, Django will provide them uniquely under the namespace we define in `STATIC_URL`, which means that we can access them like this:

```
http://example.com/static/logo.jpg
http://example.com/static/bg_tile.png
http://example.com/static/js/app.js
http://example.com/static/styles.css
http://example.com/static/styles_mobile.css
```

Long story short, independently from their physical location Django makes them accessible through the unique `/static/` url.

This is the reason why `<link href="/stylesheets/style.css".../>` didn't work. The webserver (while developing probably `runserver`, in production something like nginx or apache) just doesn't know anything about the `stylesheets` directory.

So the final step was to use Django's `static` templatetag to create the link. This ensures that if you ever change the `STATIC_URL` setting (e.g. from `/static/` to `/assets/`) you don't need to touch any of your templates because `{% static %}` resolves it correctly for you.

Once it gets to deploying your app to a live site it gets a bit more involved (but not so much), but I hope this is enough information to get you started.

Comment: amazingly, even with your change (I was doing that as we speak lol), I still get 404 on the clearly existent "mybasepath/stylesheets/screen.css". My project has in root /stylesheets/screen.css, but I get

`[01/Jun/2015 19:42:34] "GET /owners/artemis-treats/schedule/ HTTP/1.1" 200 69176
[01/Jun/2015 19:42:34] "GET /stylesheets/screen.css HTTP/1.1" 404 2546
[01/Jun/2015 19:42:37] "GET /owners/artemis-treats/ HTTP/1.1" 200 5771
[01/Jun/2015 19:42:37] "GET /stylesheets/screen.css HTTP/1.1" 404 2546
GET
[01/Jun/2015 19:42:38] "GET /owners/artemis-treats/schedule/ HTTP/1.1" 200 69176`

Comment: I just noticed your answer was 2 part, allow me to try

Comment: would you mind explaining why it didnt work before? I cant see any problems with it calling to /stylesheets/screen.css even though it was there. Why does {% static "screen.css" %} fix it, when screen.css was where I said it was?

Comment: sure, I extended the answer and hope it helps.